# Reading non-breaking space in html results in a symbol

Tags: html, ruby, character-encoding, sinatra, nokogiri

I finally managed to parse parts of a website:

```
get '/' do
  url = '<website>'
  data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  @rows = data.css("td[valign=top] table tr") 
  erb :muster
end
```

Now I am trying to extract a certain line in my view. Therefore i put in my HTML code:

```
<%= @rows[2] %>
```

And it actually returns the code, but it has problems with a space:

```
<td class="class_name">&nbsp;</td>
```

instead it says

```
<td class="class_name">�</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In short: character encodings do not match in your pipeline between the file you are fetching, the the encoding Nokogiri applies, your Erb template, and/or the encoding specified for your resulting HTML file. The simplest (though not always easy) solution is to ensure that UTF-8 is used throughout your pipeline.

Comment: and how do I change nokogiri encoding or the erb template? I think the orginal and final html are UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

with

```
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).encode('ASCII-8BIT'))
```

This way nokogiri will not try to use UTF-8 and thus print `&nbsp;` instead of ASCII char 0xA0.